# Creating a log of a backup C#

Tags: c#, logging, backup

So I want to log what happens when I backup files but I'm not sure how to make it work for files in subdirectories aswell.
Right now I have this code that works for all files in the selected directory but doesn't work for subdirectory files

```
private void LogBackup(string sourceDirName, string destDirName)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        string logDestination = this.tbox_LogFiles.Text;
        string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_H.mm.ss");

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        lines.Add("FILES TO COPY:");
        lines.Add("--------------");

        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files
            .Where(f => !extensionsToSkip.Contains(f.Extension) && !filesToSkip.Contains(f.FullName)).ToList())
        {
            string desttemppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            string sourcetemppath = Path.Combine(sourceDirName, file.Name);
            lines.Add("SOURCE FILE:");
            lines.Add(sourcetemppath);
            lines.Add("DESTINATION FILE:");
            lines.Add(desttemppath);
            lines.Add("");
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs
            .Where(f => !foldersToSkip.Contains(f.FullName)))
        {
            //NOT SURE WHAT TO WRITE HERE
        }

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logDestination + @"\LOG " + dateString + ".txt"))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }

    }
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the [SearchOption.AllDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx) and you will get all sub directories:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

when you now loop through the directories, you will have also the first level of subdirectories and for each directory just get the files that it contains

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
{
    FileInfo[] files = subdir.GetFiles();

    ......
```